# css scale3d translate3d for tooltip effect

Tags: css, 3d, scale, transition, translate

I am trying to do the tooltip effect as the following link shows: http://tympanus.net/Development/TooltipStylesInspiration/line.html

I have the following source code on JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0b5gpLko/

Since I am not completely following the tutorial word by word, I like to know if there is a way to hide the element `.inner` from showing until it goes above the white bar `.text{ border-bottom }`.

Thank you

Comment: should it still slide up?

Comment: yes, slide up but only show the animation above the white bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `overflow: hidden;` to `.text`, like this

```
.text {
    width: 280px;
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 10px solid #ffffff;
    transition: transform .3s .2s;
    transform: scale3d(0,1,1);
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aav0xfj7/1/)**

Comment: You're welcome ;) Sometimes the solution is just around the corner, I know that feeling :D